# AIOGRAM перелистал весь интернет, но не нашёл, как получить ответ от пользователя

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

Хочу сделать в боте опросы со своими вариантами ответа и записать их в текстовик.

Comment: Ничего непонятно, опишите точнее суть проблемы, чтобы Вам подсказали решения. Для редактирования вопроса воспользуйтесь кнопкой [Править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1317207/edit)

Comment: Нагуглил, вы это искали https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial/docs/lesson_13/ ?

Comment: Вам поможет использование конечных автоматом (FSM).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вроде как щас разобрался и работать стоит с состоянием, т.к. везде где я видел их переменение это через команды /state Ку, а оказывается состояние можно ожидать в следующем сообщении пользователя, что подходит для меня и для моего вопроса.